# How to convert a list of anchor links into a select dropdown that operates changing tabs on change of option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of anchor links that successfully fades in and out tab content on click.

I need to convert this list into a select drop-down at mobile and I'm not sure how to go about updating the current setup to function the same way except the list would be in drop-down format.

Is there a simple way to do this?

[Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ub45n9pe/1/)

JS:

```
$("#customer-content .group").hide(); // Initially hide all content
$("#customer-tabs li:first").attr("id","current"); // Activate first tab
$("#customer-content .group:first").fadeIn(); // Show first tab content

$('#customer-tabs li a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($(this).attr("id") == "current"){ //detection for current tab
    return       
  }
  else{             
    $("#customer-content .group").hide(); //Hide all content
    $("#customer-tabs li").attr("id",""); //Reset id's
    $(this).parent().attr("id","current"); // Activate this
    $($(this).attr('href')).fadeIn(); // Show content for current tab
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<ul id="customer-tabs" class="cs-tabs">
  <li><a href="#link-1">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#link-2">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#link-3">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="customer-content">
  <div class="group" id="link-1">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <div class="customer-accordion">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="group" id="link-2">
    <h2>Title 2</h2>
    <div class="customer-accordion">
      Content 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="group" id="link-3">
    <h2>Title 3</h2>
    <div class="customer-accordion">
      Content 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find relevant `.group` by index, So use `.index()` to finding index of selected option and use `.eq()` to select `.group` by index.

```js
$("#customer-content .group").hide().first().fadeIn();
$('#customer-tabs').change(function(e) {      
  var i = $(this).find(":selected").index();
  $("#customer-content .group").hide().eq(i).fadeIn(); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="customer-tabs">
  <option selected>Link 1</option>
  <option>Link 2</option>
  <option>Link 3</option>
</select>
<div id="customer-content">
  <div class="group" id="link-1">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <div class="customer-accordion">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="group" id="link-2">
    <h2>Title 2</h2>
    <div class="customer-accordion">
      Content 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="group" id="link-3">
    <h2>Title 3</h2>
    <div class="customer-accordion">
      Content 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I appreciate you taking the time to share. I'll take a look at this now.